# Getting next sibling values from xml file into java based on JComboBox value and printing in console

Tags: java, xml, swing, jaxb, jcombobox

I have a xml file:

```
<Generic_Name>
<Name>
<All>Home</All>
<link>value1</link>
</Name>
<Name>
<All> Filter</All>
<link>value2</link>
</Name>
</Generic_Name>
```

I need to get the value of `<All>` tags in a combo box.When the user select the combo box value (that is the value of `<All>`)its corresponding `<link>` value need to be printed in the console. I am getting the values of `All` to the combo box but I cannot get `<link>` values printed

```
 DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
    domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse("generic.xml");
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    // XPath Query for showing all nodes value
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//Name/*/text()");
    Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
    final DefaultComboBoxModel assignGp = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
    // for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i+)
    int i = 0;
    while (i < nodes.getLength()) {
        assignGp.addElement(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());
        i = i + 2;
        }
    final JComboBox assignCombo = new JComboBox(assignGp);
    assignCombo.setSelectedIndex(0);
    assignCombo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String selct=assignCombo.getSelectedItem().toString();
        // assignGp.getSelectedItem(nodes.item(i).getNextSibling());
        }
        });
    assignCombo.setBounds(150, 180, 140, 25);
    panel.add(assignCombo);
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example). 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(Same recommendation as Oliver Watkins (+1), using a JAXB approach)**

You're making it difficult for yourself, doing it this way. You should just map your xml to java object. Say have `Name` class with `all` and `link` fields. I'm not great with dom and xpath, but if you are then just traverse the entire xml and map each set to a `Name` object and add all those `Name` objects to the `DefaultListModel`. Override the `toString()` of the `Name` class to just return the `all` field, that way, only the `all` field is rendered in the `JComboBox`

A much easier way that using dom/xpath, is to use [JAXB](https://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_1_1-Introduction.html#Introduction) which will do the binding for your, with [annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/customize.html).

Tested Example:

Root Element class

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Generic_Name")
public class GenericName {

    @XmlElement(name = "Name")
    protected List<Name> name;

    public List<Name> getNames() {
        if (name == null) {
            name = new ArrayList<Name>();
        }
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Name class

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Name", propOrder = {
    "all",
    "link"
})
public class Name {

    @XmlElement(name = "All", required = true)
    protected String all;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String link;

    // getters and setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return all;
    }
}
```

Result: Using `Unmarshaller` to unmarshal the xml. Passing the top level element type `GenericName.class`, when the xml is unmarshalled, a `GenericName` instance will be created, with the list of `Names`

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class TestComboJaxB {

    private static final String FILE_PATH = "src/combobox/genericname.xml";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                File file = new File(FILE_PATH);
                ComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(getNames(file).toArray());
                final JComboBox cbox = new JComboBox(model);
                cbox.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        Name name = (Name)cbox.getSelectedItem();
                        System.out.println(name.getLink());
                    }
                });
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, cbox);
            }
        });
    }

    private static List<Name> getNames(File file) {
        List<Name> names = null;
        try {
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(GenericName.class);
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
            GenericName genericName = (GenericName)unmarshaller
                    .unmarshal(file);
            names = genericName.getNames();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return names;
    }
}
```

Xml file used

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Generic_Name>
    <Name>
        <All>Home</All>
        <link>value1</link>
    </Name>
    <Name>
        <All> Filter</All>
        <link>value2</link>
    </Name>
</Generic_Name>
```

[image]

**Resources:**

- [Oracle JAXB Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/)
- [Tutorial from JAXB Specification](https://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should try a more object-oriented approach.

You should create an object called **NameEntity**, and inside it have the properties **All** and **Link**.

Iterate over your XML and create an arrayList of NameEntities.

Now iterate over the arrayList and add the elements to your combobox. You can either implement **toString()** to make NameEntity print the **All** attribute, or you can use a **ListCellRenderer** to explicitly render the value of NameEntitiy.

Read up here :

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html

Now in **actionPerformed(..)** you will get a NameEntity instead of a String. To get the corresponding Link value, you just have to call

```
NameEntity ne = (NameEntity)assignCombo.getSelectedItem();
ne.getLink();
```